# Creating, and updating a table or matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to create a matrix or table that is either an empty matrix or a table only of headers. That will add to the bottom row, that is i.e. not overwriting existing data, and not dependent on table/matrix placement indecies.

---

Example i have and empty matrix

```
A = []
```

I now get some data

```
x = [1 2 3]
```

I want to update A so that it becomes

```
A = [1 2 3]
```

Now, i get even more data

```
z = 4 5 3
```

and A becomes

```
A = [1 2 3,
     4 5 3]
```

And so forth and so on.

x and z does not exist at the same time.

Comment: See [Matlab - add element to vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188058/matlab-add-element-to-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` and `z` are row vectors, you can do this by-

```
A=x;
A=[A;z];
//and so forth
```

If they are column vectors, you can do-

```
A=x;
A=[A x];
//and so forth
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can say:

```
>> A = [];
>> x = [1 2 3];
>> z = [4 5 6];
```

and then to append them you can say

```
>> A = [A;x]
A =
     1     2     3
>> A = [A;z]
A =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```