# How to add an element to the end of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to add an element to the end of a matrix and i dont know the length of the matrix.

```
EvantCal = 999*ones(1,2);
.
.
.
.
%// in a different function
EventCal(end + 1) = [1, 3]; 
%// the numbers are random
.
.
.
```

this is the error I get when I run the code:

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Comment: `EvantCal (end+1,:) = [1, 3];`

Answer (score 1):

The error is becasue you a trying to stuff a *1*-by-*2* matrix (i.e. `[1, 3]`, which is also the `B` from the error message) into a single element of `EventCal` (note that the `I` in the error message is your `end+1` which is a single element). Rather try

```
EventCal(end+1,:) = [1, 3]
```

Here the `:` refers to *all the columns* which in your case is 2. Hence 1 row (`end+1` is a single number) and 2 columns thus exactly matching the dimensions of your *2*-by*1* matrix you are trying to append.

Also, if performance isn't a major issue, you can also use matrix concatenation (but this is [less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188190/1011724) than the indexing approach):

```
EventCal = [EventCal; [1,3]]
```

Comment: thanks, this works but not in the way im trying, i need it to go to the next line so it will look like a matrix and not an array

Comment: Sorry, just reread the question and saw your initialization. See the edit

Comment: @user2336124 no problem, please mark this as correct if it solved your issue.