# filling an empty cell dynamically

Tags: arrays, matlab

Lets suppose we have a structure v which has variable number of elements in its objects

```
>> v(1).a = 1:10;
>> v(2).a = 1:20;
>> v(3).a = 1:30;
```

Now if we want to put it into a cell array we can simply concatenate and we will have a a with 3 cells with in

```
>> c = {v(1).a,v(2).a,v(3).a}

c = 

    [1x10 double]    [1x20 double]    [1x30 double]
```

and we can access any element within cell by using

```
c{i}(j)
```

but now for example if i have to fill the same array dynamically in a for loop

```
c = v(1).a
for i= 2:numel(v)
    c= {c ,v(i).a};
end
```

for the first 2 iterations it works in the same way as  `c = {v(1).a,v(2).a}`

```
c = 

[1x10 double]    [1x20 double]
```

but after the 3rd iteration it converts the first two array into a cell with a cell

```
c = 

{1x2 cell}    [1x30 double]
```

how can avoid this ? and create a cell of array instead, like the first case, using a for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating `c` as a cell array and then appending cell arrays to it:

```
c = {v(1).a}
for i = 2:numel(v)
    c = [c, {v(i).a}];
end
```

or with a simpler initialisation:

```
c = {};
for i = 1:numel(v)
    c = [c , {v(i).a}];
end
```

However, you can do it much more simply with a one-liner:

```
c = { v.a }
```

This last solution is a MATLAB "comma-separated list" and is a convenient way to build arrays and cell arrays.
If you type `v.a` at the command line you'll see you get three answers returned (namely `v(1).a`, `v(2).a`, `v(3).a`). By writing `{ v.a }` it's equivalent to writing those three answers, separated by commas, i.e. equivalent to `{v(1).a, v(2).a, v(3).a}`.

Comment: Yes i could but actually i am using this in a call back function , each time the call back function is called it adds a new cell , but your first 2 solutions solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this approach:

```
c = {};
for i = 1:numel(v)
    c{end+1} = v(i).a;
end
```

or

```
c = {};
for i = 1:numel(v)
    c(end+1) = {v(i).a};
end
```

which I suspect ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188190/1011724)) will be faster than the concatenation approach proposed by Justin.

Comment: Dan makes a good point. For a large number of elements this is the way to go, otherwise you may create a new `c` each time, rather than just appending..

Comment: I just ran your and justins approach using a timer and your one is faster even for just appending3 elements, i agree with Justin that for a large array this is definetely the way to go

Comment: @Umar I would argue for the readability of this approach as well and also it will work weather `c` is a column or a row matrix where the concatenation approach would require `,` changed to a `;`